# for var in string returning all vars in string Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop

My code:

```
text="Qmfbtf fbu nf" 
for f in text:
    print "f"
```

In an ideal situation the output would print 4 f's
However it is returning one f per character in the string.
It seems to be using my statement as for string in text.
How do I get it to execute per "f" in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the letter 'f' for each character in the string text, because you are doing a loop on each character.

You'll need a condition before printing:

```
text="Qmfbtf fbu nf" 
for char in text:
    if char == "f":
        print "f"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `f` in `for f in text:` is a *variable name*; you could have named it anything else and the loop would not have changed. This would be the same:

```
for character in text:
```

because that's exactly what the loop does; iterate over every character in the string `text`.

You'd have to test if that character is the letter `f`:

```
for character in text:
    if character == 'f':
        print 'f'
```

You could also use the [`str.count()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count how many times `f` appears:

```
print 'f\n' * text.count('f')
```

This prints `f` plus a newline, as many times as there are `'f'` letters in your input text.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the text but missing the required steps to print out 'f' each iteration.

```
for f in text:
    if 'f' == f.lower(): 
        print 'f'
```

.lower() turns f into lowercase if there is a capital 'F' it will catch it or otherwise it wont print f.